# Can I recover root password over ssh?

Tags: root

I have a headless server and I think I lost my root password. I do not know how to fix that. Actually I do not remember setting it in the first place. I just remember being prompted a password for the first user I created.

Comment: In Ubuntu by default there is no root password, root account is locked and you can't login to it. The user you created can act as root using `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I recover root password over ssh?

No. Passwords can not be recovered without getting access to `/etc/shadow` and that requires your sudo password or physical access. And I assume you mean sudo password for the main user/admin user.

You can reset a password but that too requires physical access to the machine and it can be reset using ...

- grub rescue mode
- a live session

No physical access means you do not own the machine if you do not know the admin password. If it was possible to reset it that way anyone all over the world could be able too.

A couple of things:

Brute force attack might work if you can get a copy of your `/etc/shadow` but that one is not readable by anyone else than "root" so you would need to have made a copy of the file prior (when you still knew the password). If you have a 2nd Ubuntu install [john the ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) and you can brute force the passwords in `/etc/shadow`. Otherwise this too requires to boot the system into grub rescue or a live session to get this file onto a machine you do own.

Cloud servers you get "physical" access to through the cloud console where you can detach your system disk and attach it to another instance as the data disk. You can then find `/etc/shadow` at the mountpoint and use brute force softwate like John the ripper to extract the password.

Comment: For cloud servers, you can just mount your system's root partition on another cloud server and edit files (like `/`<mount-dir>`/etc/shadow`) there.

Comment: @FedKad good one :D

Comment: If the root directory gets mounted under a running system somewhere on the cloud … then `sudo chroot` to that root directory and `sudo passwd user` and voila :-) … I did +1 earlier by the way.